# Number items in the list, what is the threshold value when we apply view to share-point online?

Tags: office-365, list-view, custom-list, list-view-threshold

I had created list in O365 share-point online site, and about 6k items were there, 
But when I applied view group by some field it will showing only 5k items, Is there any solution to get all items by applying group by using the view?

Answer (score 2):

For On-Premise you can do this by modifying  Resource Throttling page in Central Administration. In SharePoint Online, the list view threshold is 5,000 which cannot be modified.

[Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2759051) reads

> To work around this issue, split the items into multiple lists so that
>   no list exceeds 5,000 items. Because you'll be unable to view the list
>   items beyond the limit of 5,000 items, you must configure
>   metadata-based navigation so that you can access all the list's
>   contents.
>
> To enable metadata-based navigation, follow the "Enable Metadata
>   Navigation and Filtering" and "Configure Metadata Navigation" sections
>   of the following Microsoft website: